# Speed up MySQL inner join with LIKE clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-update, inner-join

I have the following 2 tables, api_analytics_data, and telecordia.

```
CREATE TABLE `api_analytics_data` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `upload_file_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `partNumber` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `clei` varchar(45) DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(150) DEFAULT NULL,
  `processed` tinyint(1) DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_aad_clei` (`clei`),
  KEY `idx_aad_pn` (`partNumber`),
  KEY `id_aad_processed` (`processed`),
  KEY `idx_combo1` (`partNumber`,`clei`,`upload_file_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `telecordia` (
  `tid` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ProdID` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Mfg` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Pn` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Clei` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Series` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Dsc` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Eci` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `AddDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ChangeDate` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `Cost` float DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`tid`),
  KEY `telecordia.ProdID` (`ProdID`) USING BTREE,
  KEY `telecordia.clei` (`Clei`),
  KEY `telecordia.pn` (`Pn`),
  KEY `telcordia.eci` (`Eci`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Users upload data via a web interface using Excel/CSV files into api_analytics_data. The data contains EITHER the partNumbers or CLEIs. I then update the api_analytics_data table by joining the telecordia table. The telecordia table is the master list of partNumber and Cleis.

So if a user uploads a file of CLEIs, the update/join I use is:

```
update api_analytics_data aad
  inner join telecordia t on aad.clei = t.Clei
  set aad.partNumber = t.Pn
  where aad.partNumber is null
  and aad.upload_file_id = 5;
```

It works quickly, but not very thoroughly. The problem I have is that the CLEI uploaded may only be a substring of the CLEI in the telecordia table.

For example, the uploaded CLEI may be "**5SC1DX0**". In the telcordia table, the correct matching row is:

```
tid:        184324    
ProdID:     472467  
Mfg:        PLSE 
Pn:         AUA58-2-REV-E            
Clei:       5SC1DX04AA        
Series:     null
Dsc:        DL SGL-PTY POTS CU RT                
Eci:        205756    
AddDate:    1994-03-18      
ChangeDate: 1998-04-13     
Cost:       null
```

So obviously my update doesn't work in this case, even though **5SC1DX0** and **5SC1DX04AA** are the same part.

What I need is a wildcard search. However, when I try this, it is crazy slow. With about 4500 rows uploaded into the api_analytics_data table, it runs for about 10 minutes, and then loses the connection with the server.

```
update api_analytics_data aad
  inner join telecordia t on aad.clei like concat(t.Clei,'%')
  set aad.partNumber = t.Pn
  where aad.partNumber is null 
  and aad.upload_file_id = 5;
```

Is there a way to optimize this so that it runs quickly?

Comment: make sure the following have indexes: aad.clei, t.Clei, aad.partNumber, aad.upload_file_id

Comment: If you are using MySQL 5.6 and above, you can use the Fulltext search feature enabled for the table/column at time of creation or alter the table to enable it. You can find more details about it [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-search.html#function_match)

Comment: `idx_aad_pn` - this index is redundant

Answer (score 2):

The correct answer is "no".  The better course of action is to create a new column in `telecordia` with the *correct* `Clei` value in it, one that can be used for joining the tables.  In the most recent versions of MySQL, this can even be a computed column and be indexed.

That said, you might be able to do something if the matching portion is always the same length.  If so, try this:

```
update api_analytics_data aad inner join
       telecordia t
       on t.Clei = left(aad.clei, 7)
  set aad.partNumber = t.Pn
  where aad.partNumber is null and aad.upload_file_id = 5;
```

For this query, you want an index on `api_analytics_data(upload_fiel_id, partNumber, clei)` and `telecordia(clei, pn)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no "correct" CLEI. These part identifiers are all varying lengths, and are made up of different codes. So for CLEI 'SP3QAF0BAA', SP is the family code, 3Q is the subFamily code, AF0 is a feature code, B is a reference code, and AA is a complimental code. So SP3QA, SP3QAF, SP3QAF0, SP3QAF0B, etc are all the same part.

Comment: @scott80109 . . . Sounds like you need a reference table to me.